# How to get all value of invalid characters in a string in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a jquery method that check special character as shown below:

```
function checkForSpecialChar(val) {

    if (val != 0 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(val) == false) {

        return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

This is working fine as it validate the value correctly.

However now I need to get all invalid characters for the val string and show it to the user.

So for example `if val is = 123gdf$£!`
It should get only the invalid character which is `$£!`.

Any idea how i can do that please?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invert your regex by adding `^` inside `[]`

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9- ] // match anything that is not alphanumerical, `-` or whitespace
```

```js
alert(
  'Invalid characters of "123gdf$£!": '
  + (
    '123gdf$£!'.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]/g)
      .join('')
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var val = "123gdf$£!".replace(new RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]", "g"), "");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1816/

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use string match() method of javascript.

Here it is:

```
var val= "123gdf$£!";
var result= str.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/);
```

result will be an array with values.